# Can I use the nRF8001 Bluefruit LE Breakout on 3.3V instead of 5V on my Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an nRF8001 Bluefruit LE Breakout module and when I check images on how to wire it, the schematic looks like this with the 5V connection:

[image]

I was wondering whether it was possible to use the 3.3V instead. I looked at the documentation, it says this:

> By connecting 5.0V on the VIN pin, all of the signals will be level shifted between 5V for the Arduino and 3.3V for the nRF8001, meaning you don't need to worry about damaging the IC by providing logic levels that it can't safely handle.

And this, which confirms that it works, right?

> If you are using 3.3V logic, simply connect 3.3V from your development board to the VIN pin on the nRF8001 breakout.

I am pretty new, so I want to make sure, so I do not destroy any modules.

https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/hooking-everything-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That nRF8001 board runs on 3.3V. And do make sure that using it with a 5V-Arduino, they put a regulator that steps down 5V to 3.3V. Which is why if you have 3.3V already, you connect it to Vin, and you're good to go.

Comment: Ok I use a standard arduino uno board. So i if i understand correctly and to make sure: Vin of the nRF8001 to the 3.3V of the arduino uno with a cable and i am good to go?

Comment: Yep. And don't forget the ground pin :-)

Comment: Awesome :) Yes exactly!! Thanks. Will upvote answer (can do it in 6 min stackoverflow says)

Comment: Yes will do it asap!

Comment: Seems to be working very well! I get connection in the serial monitor :) Awesome. I am very close to finish my first robot!